# Brand new WD MyPassport can't be initialized or used

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive

Got a brand new 4TB Western Digital My Passport portable hard drive. Plugged it in, won't show up in `Computer`. I also tried the following options with no luck.

- Running Windows 8.1
- Also tried in Windows 10 on another machine
- Tried a different cable

**1) Devices and Printers:**

[image]

---

**2) Device Manager:**

[image]

---

**3) Disk Management:**

[image]

---

Now some thorough Googling tells me that the problem is that the drive is not initialized.

However, trying to intialize the drive using `MBR` results in this error:
`The system cannot find the file specified`

[image]

and trying GPT results in this:

[image]

`The specified disk is not convertible because the size is less than the minimum size required for GPT disks.`

---

**Other software:**

I also tried a tool called `MiniTool Partition Wizard` as well as several WD applications but none of them could detect and list the drive.

---

**Edit:** WD gave me a full refund.

Comment: Did you try to update the hard disk driver from the manufacturer website ?

Comment: Also this might not be useful but worth the shot try using testdisk from here http://html5.litten.com/updated-how-to-fix-external-disk-drive-suddenly-became-raw/

Comment: @Elie The manufacturer (WD) says users must use their hard drive utilities software to update drivers. And none of their utilities can detect my drive. There doesn't seem to be anywhere I can enter a product code and download off their site. I also tried Windows driver search but no luck!

Comment: You said it worked ok other pcs try updating it from other pcs

Comment: @Elie sorry, I reworded my first para, this HDD never actually worked on any other PC.

Comment: i think its a hardware issue then if it didn't work on any other pc or OS you may need to contact the Manufacturer or wherever you bought the disk from . Altho it doesn't harm to test it one last time using an enclosure

Comment: @Elie its a portable hard drive with a sealed plastic case. How can I use it with an enclosure?

Comment: if you couldn't take it back with a warranty then you have to open the plastic cover inside there is a normal HDD that fits into another enclosure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the additional information you have supplied since my previous answer it is clear to me that the disk has a hardware malfunction.

You will have to RMA it.
It doesn't matter you bought it overseas. WD warranty has nearly worldwide coverage. Just check the WD website for a local service-center and RMA procedures.

Comment: Sent it back. Any idea how long WD takes to process something like this?

Comment: @john Varied a lot from 1 to 6 weeks when I dealt with them. But that isn't saying much as that was 3-4 years ago. Given that it is the Christmas season... I don't expect it will be quick.

Answer (score 2):

Windows sometimes seems to get confused with disks that are slightly smaller than 4 TB and have 4 KB sectors size, which seems to be the case here. Windows won't put an MBR partition table on it because the 4K sectors and will not write a GPT table because the disk is smaller than 4 TB.
However if your write the GPT partition using another tool Windows will be happy to use it.

Go to http://gparted.org and download a copy of the GPartEd bootcd/bootable USB.
(Warning: gparted.com also exists and is NOT the same thing!!!)

Boot from the GParted mini Linux Distro. From there you can use the tools to write a GPT partition table to the disk. After that Windows should be able to handle the disk as a normal drive.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Is there a difference between this bootable version and the Linux application GParted?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any difference.  If you already have a machine with Linux installed, or if you have a live Linux CD such as Knoppix, you can use that.

Comment: Update: sadly this doesn't work as the drive is not detected. Anything I can try to get the drive to show up in GParted?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your drive. You like me probably set a password for accessing the drive the last time you used it. Just use the WD drive utilities software to enter the pass and initialize it, otherwise you won't be able to initialize the drive using disk manager.

Comment: WD offered me a full refund so there must have been something wrong with it. Also, no, I did not set a password. I faced this issue right out of the box.